# How to append title by use pandas DataFrame to_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
sqldata = hiveSql.sql("""
        SELECT name,age from DB
""")

tabel_df = pd.DataFrame(data=sqldata.collect())
tabel_df.to_csv('resultRDD.csv')
```

As the code show, I have the CSV just like as below:

```
tom  16
jack 18
```

Actually，I need the CSV like as below

```
name age
tom  16
jack 18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a column names list:

```
table_df = pd.Dataframe(data=sqldata.collect())

#add these 2 lines
column_names = ['name','age']
table_df.columns = column_names

table_df.to_csv('resultRDD.csv')
```

That's it. It's Done!

Answer (score 0):

you can also pass in a list of column names like

```
tabel_df = pd.DataFrame(data=sqldata.collect(),columns=['name','age'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
tabel_df.to_csv('resultRDD.csv', header=['name','age'])
```

Answer (score 0):

by my own own way

```
tabel_df = pd.DataFrame(data=sqldata.collect(),columns=sqldata.columns)
```

also can work,Thx ALL